# Google Charts com SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5, google-charts

Olá, estou tentando desenvolver alguns gráficos em uma aplicação web asp.net MVC 5, quanto ao desenvolvimento do relatório, tranquilo, deixando com informações fixas. Mas, como posso integrar o gráfico com as informações em uma tabela do banco de dados? Estou usando Entity Framework com SQL Server. Efetuei vários testes, entretanto não consigo povoar o gráfico com informações do banco de dados.

-> Visualização, aqui esta passando os valores de forma estática para o gráfico, mas preciso recuperar a informação do banco de dados. tenho uma coluna 'Confima', quero pegar o total que esta como true e o total que esta como false.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutGrafico.cshtml";
}

@section head_scripts{
            <!--Load the AJAX API-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

      // Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
      // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
      // draws it.
      function drawChart() {

        // Create the data table.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
        data.addRows([
          ['Confirmado', 30],
          ['Cancelado', 10]
        ]);

        // Set chart options
        var options = {'title':'Relação de pesquisas Confirmadas e Canceladas',
                       'width':600,
                       'height':500};

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
</script>
    }

<div class="container">
    <h1 class="page-header">Gráfico de Pesquisas</h1>
    <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
</div>
```

-> Esta é minha classe model, responsável pela criação da tabela no banco de dados.

```
namespace SistemaGerencial.Models.Gerencial
{
    public class PesquisaProduto
    {
        [Key]
        public int PesquisaId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Codigo Produto")]
        public int CodPro { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Codigo de Barras")]
        public string CodBar { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Nome Produto")]
        public string Nome { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Valor unitário")]
        public decimal Valor { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Quantidade informada")]
        public decimal Qtd { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Valor Total")]
        public decimal Total { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Produto foi confirmado?")]
        public bool Confimado { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime DataPesquisa { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    }
```

-> Classe Controller

```
private ControleContext db = new ControleContext();
        // GET: GraficoPesquisa
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Poderia postar como está o seu código? Quais dados você deseja povoar?

Comment: Randrade, nesta situação necessito do total de produtos confirmados e total de produtos que não foram confirmados, informação esta salva na coluna 'confima'. No gráfico necessito demonstrar estes totais.

Answer (score 1):

Resolução para o problema estava tendo:

- Controller

```html
 public class GraficoController : Controller
        {
            private ControleContext db = new ControleContext();
            // GET: Grafico
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                return View();
            }
        
            public JsonResult Data()
            {
                var teste = db.PesquisaProdutoes.Count(c => c.Confimado.Equals(true));
                var teste1 = db.PesquisaProdutoes.Count(c => c.Confimado.Equals(false));
        
                List<object> obj = new List<object>();
                obj.Add(new
                {
                    Pesquisa = "Confirmado",
                    Quantidade = teste
                });
                obj.Add(new
                {
                    Pesquisa = "Cancelado",
                    Quantidade = teste1
                });
        
                return Json(obj, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
```

- Visualização

```html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutGrafico.cshtml";
}

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            url: '@Url.Action("Data","Grafico")',
            success: function (result) {
                google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
                google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function () {
                    drawChart(result);
                });
            }
        });

        function drawChart(result) {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'Pesquisa');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Quantidade');
            var dataArray = [];
            $.each(result, function (i, obj) {
                dataArray.push([obj.Pesquisa, obj.Quantidade]);
            });


            data.addRows(dataArray);

            var pierchart_options = {
                title: 'Relação de pesquisas Confirmadas e Canceladas',
                width: 500,
                height: 400,
            };
            var pierchart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('pierchart_div'));
            pierchart.draw(data, pierchart_options);

            var barchart_options = {
                title: 'Relação de pesquisas Confirmadas e Canceladas',
                width: 500,
                height: 400,
                legend: 'none'
            };
            var barchart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('barchart_div'));
            barchart.draw(data, barchart_options);
        }
    });
</script>

<div class="container">
    <h1 class="page-header">Gráfico de pesquisas</h1>
    <table class="columns">
        <tr>
            <td><div id="pierchart_div" style="border: 1px solid #ccc"></div></td>
            <td><div id="barchart_div" style="border: 1px solid #ccc"></div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

- Resultado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]